# Algorithm to produce random number with a gamma distribution

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, probability-distributions, gamma-function

I'd like to produce pseudo-random numbers with different distributions for a Monte Carlo simulation.

I've got the poisson distribution working nicely with an algorithm from Knuth. I'm having trouble getting a nice easy and fast algorithm for a power distribution. The gamma distribution should do, but the article in wikipaedia gives an algorithm, but remarks that it's not a good one, without providing a link to a better one.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Generating_gamma-distributed_random_variables

Is there a good, fast algorithm for a gamma distribution?

Comment: Luc Devroye has often commented on the challenges of producing gamma variates and is purported to maintain an open offer of fine Belgian beer to the discoverer of a "one-line algorithm". If you are interested in random-variate generation and don't know the name Luc Devroye, you need to. See also [this small appetizer](http://luc.devroye.org/handbooksimulation1.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difficulty mentioned in Wikipedia refers to gamma distributions with small shape parameter; this has been addressed in [arXiv:1302.1884](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1884):

> The gamma distribution with small shape parameter can be difficult to
>   characterize. For this reason, standard algorithms for sampling from
>   such a distribution are often unsatisfactory. In this paper, we first
>   obtain a limiting distribution for a suitably normalized gamma
>   distribution when the shape parameter tends to zero. Then this
>   limiting distribution provides insight to the construction of a new,
>   simple, and highly efficient acceptance--rejection algorithm.
>   Pseudo-code and an R implementation for this new sampling algorithm
>   are provided.